# Pandas multiply column by another column in all rows below

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to multiply a column by ALL values in another column below it. So for example:

```
r5,colC = (r5,colA * r6,colB) + 
          (r5,colA * r7,colB) + 
          (r5,colA * r8,colB)  
r6,colC = (r6,colA * r7,colB) + 
          (r6,colA * r8,colB)
```

For the time being I have a horrible looping solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[11,0.5],[12,0.4],[12,0.3],[13,0.2],[14,0.1],[15,0.6]],
                  index=[2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006],
                  columns=['A','B'])

       A                    B
2001  11                 0.50
2002  12                 0.40
2003  12                 0.30
2004  13                 0.20
2005  14                 0.10
2006  15                 0.60

df['C'] = [(df.loc[i]['A']* df['B'][df.index > i]).sum() for i in df.index]

       A                    B                    C
2001  11                 0.50                17.60
2002  12                 0.40                14.40
2003  12                 0.30                10.80
2004  13                 0.20                 9.10
2005  14                 0.10                 8.40
2006  15                 0.60                 0.00
```

Edit:

Some speed tests:

```
%timeit df['C'] = [(df.loc[i]['A']* df['B'][df.index > i]).sum() for i in df.index]
%timeit df['D'] = df.B[::-1].cumsum()[::-1].shift(-1).fillna(0) * df.A

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 505 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will achieve your objective:

```
df['C'] = df.B[::-1].cumsum()[::-1].shift(-1).fillna(0) * df.A
```

`df.B[::-1]` reverses the series, and then the cumulative sum is calculated on this reversed series, which is then reversed again to get it in the original order.  The net effect is a `cumsum` bottom up instead of top down.

You then need to shift this `cumsum` row by one and multiply it by column 'A'.

The `fillna(0)` was to match your results, otherwise the bottom number would be `NaN` because there are no rows below it.

Comment: Thanks! More than 3 times faster than my approach

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with pandas, but presumably you can hack the following method (which uses numpy) to work for you as well:

```
arr_1 = np.array([1,1,2,2,3])
arr_2 = np.array([10,20,40,80,-1])

upside_down_1 = np.flipud(arr_1)
upside_down_2 = np.flipud(arr_2)
upside_down_2 = np.concatenate(([1], upside_down_2))[:-1]
upside_down_answer = upside_down_1 * np.cumprod(upside_down_2)
answer = np.flipud(upside_down_answer)
```

The `np.cumprod` function is what's doing the magic here. The flipping upside-down is just to make it multiply with everything below the current index, rather than above/at.